# SQL Server : include last date in range between dates

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a date picker FROM DATE and TO DATE.

If the user enters FROM = `5/10/2019` and TO = `5/19/2019`, the data only returns until `5/18`, but does not include `5/19` data.

I would like it to include the `5/19` as well.

I have this T-SQL code:

```
SELECT * 
FROM TABLE 
WHERE DATE >= '5/10/2019' AND DATE <= '5/19/2019'
```

But my issue is that if the date in the TABLE is 5/19 it will not show

So I need something like this?

```
SELECT * 
FROM TABLE 
WHERE DATE >= '5/10/2019' AND DATE <= (('5/19/2019') + 1)
```

I need to include the last date as well.

Comment: Yes - you basically need to add one day to the second date picked - but I'd recommend using the `DATEADD(DAY, 1, ToDate)` function instead of just `+ 1` .....

Comment: The `BETWEEN` clause can be useful in such circumstances.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your date column probably has a time component.  The safest method is:

```
WHERE DATE >= '2019-05-10' AND
      DATE < '2019-05-20'  -- note one day later
```

You can express this as:

```
WHERE DATE >= '2019-05-10' AND
      DATE < DATEADD(DAY, 1, '2019-05-20')
```

So you can capture the inputs that you want.

SQL Server will use indexes for conversions to date, so it is also reasonable to do:

```
WHERE CONVERT(DATE, DATE) >= '2019-05-10' AND
      CONVERT(DATE, DATE) <- '2019-05-19'
```

In most databases, such conversions preclude the use of indexes, but SQL Server is an exception.

Answer (score 1):

You can just change your query so it only shows those less than (change `<=` to `<`), and then increment the date by a single day:

```
SELECT * FROM TABLE WHERE DATE >= '5/10/2019' and DATE < '5/20/2019'
```

You can increment your day by one using the [`DATEADD()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/dateadd-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) function

Comment: That would still not include 5/20/2019

Comment: @compcobalt I'm not sure I understand? Do you want to include 5/20/2019 also?

Comment: If the user Enters FROM: 5/10/2019 and TO: 5/19/2019 the data only returns until 5/18 does not include 5/19 data. I would like it to include the 5/19 as well.

Comment: So whatever date they enter at the End I want it to go up 1 more day

Comment: Yes - and you can do that by changing it to 5/20/19 and use the less than operator. Then it will include everything that is less than 5/20 (but not 5/20)

Comment: So whatever end-date they input, you just add 1 and use the less-than operator

Comment: like DATEADD(day, 1, '5/19/2019')  ??

Answer (score 0):

It all depends on the 'DATE' column type. Based on what you explained, I assume DATE is of a datetime, datetime2 of datetimeoffset type. In that case, when you write:

```sql
SELECT * 
FROM TABLE 
WHERE DATE >= '5/10/2019' AND DATE <= '5/19/2019'
```

It actually translates to:

```sql
SELECT * 
FROM TABLE 
WHERE DATE >= '5/10/2019 00:00:00' AND DATE <= '5/19/2019 00:00:00'
```

That's why you are not getting 19th May included in results (actually you are, but only midnight of May, 19th). So, there are two ways to solve this (ignoring performance):

```sql
SELECT * 
FROM TABLE 
WHERE DATE >= '5/10/2019' AND DATE <= DATEADD(DAY, 1, '5/19/2019')
```

or

```sql
SELECT * 
FROM TABLE 
WHERE DATE >= '5/10/2019' AND cast(DATE as date) <= '5/19/2019'
```